# Missing "flag" link

Tags: bug, status-completed

On Ivo's answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64/can-i-share-steam-updates-between-computers) the "flag" post link is missing.

[image]

I've checked other posts at random and they all seem to be OK. This has been consistently missing too.

I should have added I'm running Google Chrome (5.0.375.99) on Windows-XP.

Comment: I can see the flag option on my screen - XP on IE8.

Comment: I can see it as well. FireFox 3.6 on Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

You can't flag a post that you have accepted as an answer. For example, I am missing the link on [What are the major differences between the different versions of the PS3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117/what-are-the-major-differences-between-the-different-versions-of-the-ps3/138#138), which is an answer I accepted. The same occurs on the Trilogy as well, so it's always been a feature that I guess we overlook.

Comment: Ah - I never noticed that before! I did think it was to do with it being an answer to my question but there were flags on other answers. I guess it's because I don't usually ask questions ;) And lo! the "flag" link on this post has disappeared for me.

Answer (score 1):

We're going to allow flagging for moderator attention on any accepted answers that you've marked.  Indeed, any post should be allowed to have moderators informed about it.

This will be pushed out tonight.